# Is using OZ's ReentrancyGuard contract infallible?

Tags: openzeppelin, reentrant-attacks

Are there any know ways to exploit reentry even if a contract is using Reentrancyguard from OpenZeppelin? This is for an audit contest...it's not me trying to exploit anything.